# GE Dryer, Model GTDX100EM1WW Burnt Wiring

Tags: dryer, appliances, wire

White wire connecting to the door switch has burned through and detached from the connector head. There are also burn marks on the dryer drum.

I know at least temporarily fixing this is merely stripping the wire, crimping it to a new connector, and plugging it in... But why did this happen and how can I prevent it?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if the red connector in the first photo may not be the original, but a past DIY repair. I may be wrong, too.

Either way the wire should have a retaining clip close to the connection. The plastic grate in photo 1 most likely has a clip close to the terminal. If not zip tie the wires to a stable part of the dryer.

This most likely occurred due to vibration and the wire not being secured. If necessary solder the spade terminal to the wire for the most secure connection.